# Chained variable assignment in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm puzzled by how Julia handles the block of code below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a .= a/2 .= o = a .* 2
```

The output for both 'a' and 'o' is [2,4,6]. However, I don't understand why the result for 'a' is the same as if I had used `a .= a*2`. Is `a/2` treated as a variable and passed the array `[2,4,6]` (the result of `a*2`)? And then this "variable" `a/2` is passed to `a`? I would have expected `a` to have stayed as `[1,2,3]`. I'm uncertain as to whether Julia executes these operations in a specific order.

Comment: `a/2` returns a temporary, unnamed, vector, which subsequently is filled with the values `[2,4,6]`. And then `a` is filled with those values again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `a / 2` creates a new array which initially contains the values you expect (`[1,2,3]`) however the contents of that array are immediately overwritten by a broadcast assignment with the contents in the right hand side array.

Let's break down the entire expression, Julia can help us:

```
julia> :(a .= a/2 .= o = a .* 2)
:(a .= (a / 2 .= (o = a .* 2)))
```

By looking at the parentheses inserted when the `Expr` is printed we see the subexpressions a bit more clearly. As you can see the top expression is `a .= (result of everything on RHS)`.

Let's evaluate it in the REPL:

```
julia> o = a .* 2
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 4
 6
   
julia> a / 2 .= (o = a .* 2)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 4.0
 6.0
                  
julia> a .= (a / 2 .= (o = a .* 2))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 4
 6
```

As you can see the array created by `a / 2` is a Float64 array and the values are therefore converted and then converted back to Int64 when put into `a`.

We can make the right hand side expression even more explicit by using `Meta.show_sexpr`.

```
julia> :(a/2 .= o = a .* 2) |> Meta.show_sexpr
(:.=, (:call, :/, :a, 2), (:(=), :o, (:call, :.*, :a, 2)))
```

let's add some whitespace for clarity:

```
(:.=,
  (:call, :/, :a, 2),
  (:(=),
    :o,
    (:call, :.*, :a, 2)))
```

so this expression is broadcast assigning to the value that is returned by calling the `/` function on the arguments `a` and `2`. The value that is assigned is what the assignment `o = a * 2` returns.